# Injecting Service to Service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I built an Angular Application via Visual Studio Template.

Following structure is given:

- /Clientapp
- ./app/app.module.shared.ts
- ./app/app.module.client.ts
- ./app/app.module.server.ts
- ./components/*
- ./services/person-data.service.ts
- ./services/auth-http.service.ts
- ./boot-client.ts
- ./boot-server.ts

So in the person-data.service.ts I want to use the auth-http.service.ts.

*person-data.service.ts*

```js
import { Person } from '../models/person'
import { Configuration } from '../constants/global.constants';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthHttpService } from '../services/auth-http.service';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(AuthHttpService)private authHttp: AuthHttpService) {

        this.actionUrl = Configuration.API_SERVER + 'api/person/';

        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    }

    public GetAll = (): Observable<Person[]> => {
        return this.authHttp.get(this.actionUrl).map((response: Response) => <Person[]>response.json());
    }
}
```

*auth-http.service.ts*

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpService {
    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(AuthService) private authService: AuthService) {

    }
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {
        console.log("AuthHttpService Get:" + url);
        if (options) {
            options = this.authService._setRequestOptions(options);
        } else {
            options = this.authService._setRequestOptions();
        }
        return this.http.get(url, options);
    }
}
```

*app.module.shared.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PersonService } from './services/person-data.service'
import { Configuration } from './constants/global.constants'
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service'
import { AuthHttpService } from './services/auth-http.service'
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthHttpService,
        Configuration,
        PersonService,
        AuthService
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
};
```

*app.module.client.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: No provider
>   for AuthHttpService!

What am I missing?

Comment: Will you please share the app.module.ts / app.module.shared.ts ?

Comment: Edited the main post. In the app.module.server.ts just the ServerModule of @angular/platform-server gets imported

Comment: `@Inject(AuthHttpService)` in `@Inject(AuthHttpService)private authHttp: AuthHttpService` is redundant. You only need it when the parameter to `@Inject(...)` is different than the type of the parameter. (Same with ` @Inject(AuthService)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the inject decorators from the constructor as they are not needed.

Then, as the error says, import then inside of the providers of your module, like:

```
providers: [
             AuthHttpService,
             // Other services here,
             { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. So easy, but somehow I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to

import `sharedConfig.providers` in the `app.module.client.ts`

**app.module.client.ts**

```
...
providers: [
        ...sharedConfig.providers,
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
    ]
...
```